# Pass Data Between Pages Showing Null Phone 8.1 UAP

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-8.1

I am trying to pass data from one page to another but for some reason it is showing up null. I dont no why

I am using the following technique i dont no if its the best way or not to load my data in from a webservice. Now te data is their in the list fine but I am wondering if i not accessing the correct method on tap to pass the data.

Please bare in mind that my control is within a hub control  it finding it fine with the loaded event but obv i dont have the sender from that so its always comming up null

```
private async void grdMovies_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{

            ProgressRing pr = new ProgressRing();
            pr.IsActive = true;

           popcornpk_Dal popcorn_dal = new popcornpk_Dal();


          MovieList movieList = await popcorn_dal.GetAllMovies();
         var listView = (ListView)sender;

        listView.ItemsSource = movieList.movie_list ;

        pr.IsActive = false;

}



private void moveListView_Tapped(object sender, TappedRoutedEventArgs e)

{

          MovieList moveInfoSelected = listMovies.SelectedItem as MovieList;

            Frame.Navigate(typeof(movieInfo), moveInfoSelected);

}
```

My Xaml For Reference

```
<HubSection x:Name="hubSectionMovies" x:Uid="hubSectionMovies" Header="Movies" Width="Auto"
                     DataContext="{Binding Groups[0]}" HeaderTemplate="{ThemeResource HubSectionHeaderTemplate}">
            <DataTemplate>
                <ListView x:Name="moveiListView"
                    ItemsSource="{Binding}"
                    IsItemClickEnabled="True"
                    Loaded="grdMovies_Loaded"
                    ContinuumNavigationTransitionInfo.ExitElementContainer="True"   SelectionChanged="moveListView_SelectionChanged" Tapped="moveListView_Tapped_1" >

                    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <Grid>
                                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

                                <Border Background="{ThemeResource ListViewItemPlaceholderBackgroundThemeBrush}" Margin="0,9.5,0,0" Grid.Column="0" HorizontalAlignment="Left">
                                    <Image Source="{Binding image}" Width="160" Height="234" Stretch="UniformToFill" AutomationProperties.Name="{Binding Title}" />
                                </Border>
                                <StackPanel Grid.Column="1" Margin="14.5,0,0,0">
                                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding name}" Style="{ThemeResource ListViewItemTextBlockStyle}"/>
                                </StackPanel>
                            </Grid>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
                </ListView>

            </DataTemplate>
        </HubSection>
```

I enclose my calss below for completeness

```
public class Movie
     {
        public string id { get; set; }
        public string name { get; set; }
        public string description { get; set; }
        public string image { get; set; }
        public string secondry_images { get; set; }
        public string actor { get; set; }
        public string actoress { get; set; }
        public string director { get; set; }
        public string music_director { get; set; }
        public string release_date { get; set; }
        public string tags { get; set; }
        public string age_restriction { get; set; }
        public string box_office { get; set; }
        public string official_site { get; set; }
        public string duration { get; set; }
        public string writers { get; set; }
        public int imdb { get; set; }
        public string status { get; set; }
        public string language { get; set; }
        public string created { get; set; }
        public string modified { get; set; }
        public string movie_category_id { get; set; }
        public string slug { get; set; }
        public string movie_show_time_id { get; set; }
        public string theatre_movie_screen_id { get; set; }
        public string videous { get; set; }
        public string videos { get; set; }
        public string comming_soon { get; set; }
        public string avg { get; set; }
     }

     public class MovieList
     {
        public List<Movie> movie_list { get; set; }
     }
```

Comment: What type of items does `MovieList` contain?

Comment: a list of movie signualr sure

Answer (score 0):

The line:

```
MovieList moveInfoSelected = listMovies.SelectedItem as MovieList;
```

in `moveListView_Tapped` will always be `null` because the `SelectedItem` will be of type `Movie`.

To make it work you need to cast is to `Movie`:

```
Movie moveInfoSelected = moveiListView.SelectedItem as Movie;
```

And make sure you handle `Movie` types in your `movieInfo` page.

**EDIT:**

First you need to **remove** the `IsItemClickEnabled="True"` from your XAML or set it to `False`.
Then you need to put your navigation code in the `SelectionChanged` handler, in your case in the method `moveListView_SelectionChanged`:

```
private void moveListView_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        var listView = sender as ListView;
        Movie moveInfoSelected = listView.SelectedItem as Movie;
        Frame.Navigate(typeof(movieInfo), moveInfoSelected);
    }
```

Comment: sorry your reading the xaml wrong had the wrong name on their should be movieListView its not findng it that is what is always staying null and cause im inside my hub control i dont no how to access ur access the hub control itself their ?

Comment: ive included my full xaml for completness

Comment: its not finding the listview that is the problem i am having i believe its that that is remaining null im afaird

Comment: it cant access the listview beceuase its underneath a hub control please look at the code again

Comment: Ok, you need to cast the `sender` to `ListView` as in my last edit.

Comment: I have done what you said but the listview is still comming back null strange is that that method for finding out the list view works fine in the loaded command in listview but not others it seems